# Cannot run libgdx's 'Animation3DTest' on Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to run the `Animation3DTest` , one of libgdx's test examples

On the desktop (lwjgl) I can run this test flawlessly, I can see a guy and a sword and I can move him around without any errors.

However, on Android, after starting this test, I got a force stop, and here is what showed on the Logcat

```
09-24 10:46:49.526 24530-24577/com.badlogic.gdx.tests.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1445
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/default.vertex.glsl (Classpath)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:133)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:563)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.length(AndroidFileHandle.java:162)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readString(FileHandle.java:192)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readString(FileHandle.java:186)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.shaders.DefaultShader.getDefaultVertexShader(DefaultShader.java:249)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.DefaultShaderProvider.<init>(DefaultShaderProvider.java:44)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch.<init>(ModelBatch.java:101)
at com.badlogic.gdx.tests.g3d.BaseG3dTest.create(BaseG3dTest.java:38)
at com.badlogic.gdx.tests.g3d.BaseG3dHudTest.create(BaseG3dHudTest.java:50)
at com.badlogic.gdx.tests.g3d.Animation3DTest.create(Animation3DTest.java:45)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:322)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1514)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1242)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the [latest nightly](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/) build. Here's the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1450).

Comment: I'm already on the September 23rd nightly and still have this bug :(

Comment: @nubhihi219 If you open the jars, do you see this file: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/default.vertex.glsl?

Comment: Yes I can see that file in my 'gdx.jar'.

Comment: @nubhihi219 If it uses the exact path (com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/), then I am not sure. I would try some other jars.